# Saving preferences of document when it is a txt file

Tags: cocoa, macos

I wonder how can I save preferences of a document such as window size, position in the screen, etc when this document is just a simple txt file. (My app is a Text Editor)

I thought of NSUserDefaults and save file path but what would happen if file is moved later when the app is closed? Using NSUserDefaults is really a good idea? 
I am looking for advice

Thanks

EDIT:
I added these two methods to MyDocument.m (Thanks to @somegeekintn @Black Frog)

```
//helper method that set NSWindow frame string in file system attributes
- (BOOL) _savePreferencesInFileAtURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL{

    const char *path = [[absoluteURL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char *name = [@"NSWindow frame" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *frameCString = [NSStringFromRect([window frame]) cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    int result = setxattr(path , name, frameCString, strlen(frameCString) + 1, 0, 0);
    return (result<0)? NO: YES;
}

//helper method that reads NSWindow frame string from file system attributes
- (BOOL) _readPreferencesInFileAtURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL{

    const char *path = [[absoluteURL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char *name = [@"NSWindow frame" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    char frameCString [50];

    ssize_t bytesRetrieved = getxattr(path, name, frameCString, 50, 0, 0); 
    //use frameCString...

    return (bytesRetrieved<0)? NO: YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at setxattr and getxattr to write and read a file's extended attributes respectively. You can put pretty much whatever you like in these attributes.

```
int setxattr(const char *path, const char *name, void *value, size_t size, u_int32_t position, int options);
ssize_t getxattr(const char *path, const char *name, void *value, size_t size, u_int32_t position, int options);
```

[setxattr man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setxattr.2.html)

Comment: @nacho4d, you will find an example of using setxattr and getxattr [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/299586-length-of-nswindow-stringwithsavedframe-result.html)